# Indicator Currency

Tags: pine-script, indicator, currency-exchange-rates

first of all I do not know a single thing about coding. I am a lawyer but like to meddle in new things.

I am trying to create a indicator to show me the price of a crypto currency in TRY as a label while in USD chart. Drop down currecy menu does not help me because I want to draw support lines on USD graph because of the high volatility of TRY.

I have managed to put together an indicator that shows me the closing price minus one percent like this:

---

'''
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © erador84

//@version=5
indicator("BuyPrice-1percent",  overlay=true)

//minus 1 percent variable

variableValue = (close*0.99)

labelText = str.tostring (variableValue)

ourLabel = label.new(x=bar_index, y=close, text=labelText, color=color.black, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_right, size=size.large)

label.set_x(id=ourLabel, x=bar_index[2])

label.delete(ourLabel[1])

### '''

I want this indicator to calculate the price in TRY.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the price of TRYUSD like below

```
tryusd=request.security("TRYUSD",timeframe.period,close)
```

Then you can divide the price by tryusd and plot the label with the same